# Terraform modules source with a condition

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have a question about the terraform modules.
Is it possible to have a condition set in the source while using terraform modules?

example:

```
module "infra_deployment" {
  source = (local.region == "SFO" ? ./modules/SFO_repo : ./modules/standard_repo)

  something here
}
```

Comment: No, its not possible.

Answer (score 0):

With pure Terraform this is not possible but can do this with Terragrunt by using generate to conditionally generate the module definition:

https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#generate

Comment: Thank You Alex. I'll try this option as well

Answer (score 0):

Using pure Terraform, I would define two modules, and use `count` to determine which one gets used:

```
module "infra_deployment_standard" {
  count  = local.region == "SFO" ? 0 : 1
  source = "./modules/standard_repo"

  something here
}

module "infra_deployment_sfo" {
  count  = local.region == "SFO" ? 1 : 0
  source = "./modules/SFO_repo"

  something here
}
```